# How to groupby in lodash for each item in a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, grouping, lodash

I have a json array of the form:

```
    [{
        "published": true,
        "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
        "categories": ["cat1"],
        "author": "some name",
        "post-format": "standard",
        "title": "Second Post,",
        "url-slug": "second-post",
        "first-published-on": "2019-03-28",
        "last-updated-on": "2019-03-28",
        "meta": {
            "title": "Second Post",
            "description": "Second post."
        },
        "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
        "path": "2019/03/28/SecondPost.md"
    }, {
        "published": true,
        "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
        "categories": ["cat1", "cat2"],
        "author": "some name",
        "post-format": "standard",
        "title": "Getting Started",
        "url-slug": "getting-started",
        "first-published-on": "2019-03-20",
        "last-updated-on": "2019-03-20",
        "meta": {
            "title": "Getting Started",
            "description": "Getting started post."
        },
        "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
        "path": "2019/03/20/GettingStarted.md"
    }]
```

I would like to group them by tags, in a form below:

```
[{
   "tag1": [{...}, {...}], 
   "tag2": [{...}, {...}], 
   "tag3": [{...}]
}]
```

I have tried to do so using lodash:

```
const groupedByTag = _.groupBy(blogMetadata, function(postmetadata) {
        postmetadata.tags.map(tag => {
          return tag
        })
      })
```

Obviously the code above is incorrect and does not work. I have looked at a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468986/lodash-groupby-nested-array), without making much headway. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can try reduce or  'json-groupby' nodejs module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` & `forEach` as an alternative of `loadash`. Inside reduce callback function iterate the `tags` and check in the accumulator object if there exist a `key` by this name. If it exist then push the current object , else create a `key` and push `value`

```js
let data = [{
  "published": true,
  "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
  "categories": ["cat1"],
  "author": "some name",
  "post-format": "standard",
  "title": "Second Post,",
  "url-slug": "second-post",
  "first-published-on": "2019-03-28",
  "last-updated-on": "2019-03-28",
  "meta": {
    "title": "Second Post",
    "description": "Second post."
  },
  "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
  "path": "2019/03/28/SecondPost.md"
}, {
  "published": true,
  "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
  "categories": ["cat1", "cat2"],
  "author": "some name",
  "post-format": "standard",
  "title": "Getting Started",
  "url-slug": "getting-started",
  "first-published-on": "2019-03-20",
  "last-updated-on": "2019-03-20",
  "meta": {
    "title": "Getting Started",
    "description": "Getting started post."
  },
  "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
  "path": "2019/03/20/GettingStarted.md"
}];

let newMapped = [data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  curr.tags.forEach(function(item) {
    if (acc[item]) {
      acc[item].push(curr)
    } else {
      acc[item] = [curr]
    }

  })
  return acc;
}, {})];


console.log(newMapped)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and  [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Here idea is

- First we loop through each element of `obj` variable.
- For each element we loop through `tags` property.
- We check if `op` already has that tag we push the value else we add a new key to `op` object with respective value

```js
let obj = [{"published": true,"tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],"categories": ["cat1"],"author": "some name","post-format": "standard","title": "Second Post,","url-slug": "second-post","first-published-on": "2019-03-28","last-updated-on": "2019-03-28","meta": {"title": "Second Post","description": "Second post."},"excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt","path": "2019/03/28/SecondPost.md"}, {"published": true,"tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],"categories": ["cat1", "cat2"],"author": "some name","post-format": "standard","title": "Getting Started","url-slug": "getting-started","first-published-on": "2019-03-20","last-updated-on": "2019-03-20","meta": {"title": "Getting Started","description": "Getting started post."},"excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt","path": "2019/03/20/GettingStarted.md"}]

let final = obj.reduce((op,inp) => {
  inp.tags.forEach(e => {
    op[e] = op[e] || []
    op[e].push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(inp)))
  }) 
  return op
},{})

console.log(final)
```